# Can Java delete all files and folders of a computer?

Tags: java, recursion, delete-file

I'm just curious (but not willing to try on my computer) what would happen if I run this code on Java?

```
 private static void deleteAll(File file)
    {
        for(File f : file.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.isFile())
            {
                f.delete();
            }
            else
            {
                deleteAll(f);
                f.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("/home");      
        deleteAll(file);
    }
```

Is this equivalent to rm -rf / in linux and will delete everything on my computer? Or will the operating system stop me from deleting System files?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Java wont have access to System Files

Comment: of course not. Your Java environment has to be installed somewhere, and that 'll be running, your OS 'll be running, ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you _can_ access system files from java...  But you won't be able to delete a bunch of things, at least those involved in _running_ the java process itself, 'cause the running process will be holding a handle open on them to stop you.  Run this from another machine (with appropriate permissions) and I can't see why you couldn't though.

Comment: That's fair, but why Linux can recursively delete itself though?

Comment: The better question is, why shouldn't it? When deleting files, let's say system ones with root priveleges, the `rm` command sends a sys-call that then executes in the OS with a system flag. There isn't a mechanism to prevent that, because the logic behind UNIX type systems is "the user knows what he/she is doing"

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't know much about Linux, but if we delete too much system files, will it come to a point where the computer doesn't even know how to "delete"?

Comment: Yes. An OS can be broken. When you are calling any command, let's say `ls` or `rm`, these command (ie programs) are loaded and then executed. If the system files are deleted (throught `rm -rf /`), then you would have some part of your OS loaded into memory, but most, if not all of it will be rendered useless and non-functioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this got my interest and I tried it on a lxc container. Now it wasn't a scientific test, but better than nothing right.

Well, I would say that I got mixed results. If you try to delete files with java normally, not system ones, then you are gonna do your work. Once you start killing your system, then thnings change. Java won't allow you to delete anything from your root directory, but I did successfuly delete my user folder (`/home/ubuntusuer`). I didn't corrupt the system, alas.

There is a mechanism to stop you from deleting a whole system. So the behaviour will not be exactly the same as compared to `rm -rf /`, but you can still remove a lot of stuff with it.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my question :)) Thank you

Comment: Sadly Java cannot delete system files. Otherwise I can trick my friends :))

Comment: Well my tests showed that, but yeah it makes sense for java to have such safety measures :) you can always try some other nice prank haha